# C# to Java of Http Session object

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, session, shopping-cart

In ASP.net, I have the following code.  I'm making a website in JSP and using Java classes.  Basically I want to incorporate the same functionality of this constructor.

What is Java code for the following c# code?

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    #region ListCart

    public List<CartItem> Items { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region CartSession


    public static readonly ShoppingCart Instance;

    static ShoppingCart()
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] == null)
        {
            Instance = new ShoppingCart();
            Instance.Items = new List<CartItem>();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] = Instance;
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = (ShoppingCart)HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's an exact analogue to this in Java. I'd normally keep a reference to the ShoppingCart inside the session itself. You'd normally access the session using HttpServletRequest.getSession(). hth

Comment: i would like to know how to know if a current session exists, if it doesnt create new one else use the one from the broweser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you will have to play with `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpSession` (which is most preferred) since you're storing a `ShoppingCart` into a session.

I would not create a ShoppingCart class to store instance of it in a Session, since ShoppingCart can exists outside of Web context. A Simple way to do what you requested is to create a utility class to store / retrieve a shopping cart in/from the session.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class ShoppingCartUtil {

    public static ShoppingCart getShoppingCart(HttpServletRequest request, String sessionName) {
        return getShoppingCart(request.getSession(), sessionName);
    }

    public static ShoppingCart getShoppingCart(HttpSession session, String sessionName) {
        return (ShoppingCart)session.getAttribute(sessionName);
    }

    public static void addShoppingCartToSession(HttpServletRequest request, String sessionName, ShoppingCart cart) {
        addShoppingCartToSession(request.getSession(), sessionName, cart);
    }

    public static void addShoppingCartToSession(HttpSession session, String sessionName, ShoppingCart cart) {
        session.removeAttribute(sessionName);
        session.setAttribute(sessionName, cart);
    }
}
```

Comment: just one question...how do i save an array list to a session

Comment: and another thing, i will be performing operations such as AddItem and SetQuantity, should i do this in this class or create a separate class for that.

right now, im a bit confused, because in asp.net, i was using the Session and the methods addItem and Setquantity all in one class

Comment: @user478636, for your first question, the same way you save a shopping cart to a session, that's the same way you save an array list

Comment: As for the `addItem`, `setQuantity`, etc. these methods exists in the `ShoppingCart` object.

Comment: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to ShoppingCart

Comment: That is the error i am getting because in ur getSession function u r returning of Type ShoppingCart, however the requestSession is of type object

Comment: Yes, ShoppingCart does extend `Object` implicitly, so typecast it e.g. `ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute(sessionName);`.